# strftime '%z', (localtime) is not working as expected in solaris machines

Tags: perl, solaris, strftime

I tried this code in linux machines,

```
my $sysdate = strftime "%Y%m%d%T", (localtime);    
my $daylight_saving_time = strftime '%z', (localtime);
```

i get below output,

```
sysdate = 2013051402:12:02    
daylight_saving_time = -0400
```

I tried same in solaries machines, i got this

```
sysdate = 2013051402:12:02
daylight_saving_time = %z
```

Anyone know the change to be done to get the daylight saving in solaries machines.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.beginners/2003/01/msg39201.html

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `POSIX::strftime` just calls your system's strftime(3), so
you get whatever that is - or - is not. %z is not part of the POSIX.1 standard
and is not consistent across systems. On other older versions of OSes, like HPUX, %z, is
the same as %Z (time zone name).  This is only for older versions.

On Solaris 8, 9 strftime does not support %z - with Solaris 10 it does.

This holds on more moderns versions Solaris 10 & Solaris 11:

%z    Replaced by offset from UTC  in  ISO  8601:2000  standard format
         (+hhmm  or  -hhmm), or by no characters if no time zone is deter-
         minable. For example, "-0430" means 4 hours 30 minutes behind UTC
         (west  of Greenwich). If tm_isdst is zero, the standard time off-
         set is used.  If tm_isdst is greater than zero, the daylight sav-
         ings  time offset if used. If tm_isdst is negative, no characters
         are returned.

So, this a  C library function issue, perl sits on top of those libraries.  I do not have a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [Date::Manip::TZ](http://search.cpan.org/~sbeck/Date-Manip-6.39/lib/Date/Manip/TZ.pod) works on Solaris:

```
   use Date::Manip::TZ;
   my $tz = new Date::Manip::TZ;
   say "tz: $tz";
```